# Where is the Terrain Toolkit ? I downloaded 1.0.2 but it's missing all the texture

Tags: unity-game-engine

Downloaded it from here:

[Toolkit](https://code.google.com/archive/p/unityterraintoolkit/downloads)

But it have only one default texture all the rest are missing.

This is a screenshot showing the only texture it have and when importing the package all the textures are missing.

Does anyone have in any chance the full toolkit package ? I'm using unity 5.3.5f1 Personal.

[image: Toolkit]

Comment: _[Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)_

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to import some textures yourself, try the built-in terrain package from unity, from menu: Assets/Import Package/Environment

It includes some basic terrain textures.

Answer (score 1):

You have the correct package, it comes without textures :) See [this video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=TZ2IXxvLq5M) to understand how it works. Texturing at is explained [at time 10:08](https://youtu.be/TZ2IXxvLq5M?t=10m8s) onward.